# linux why can't i execute a script as root

Tags: bash

I am doing some system maintenance on a linux server (oraclelinux). I have logged in as root (sudo su).
I have a script with the following permissions:
"-rwxr-xr-x."
The script is in /tmp/scripts which has permissions drwxr-xr-x
The script is owned by root:root

When I try:

## ./myscript.sh

I get:

bash permission denied

Why can't I execute my own script?
what does the period "." at the end of the file permissions mean?

Comment: Add output of `ls -lZ /tmp/scripts` to your question.

Answer (score 3):

A common security tip is to mount the `/tmp` directory with the `noexec` flag to prevent scripts from running.

Try the command

`mount | grep tmp`

and see what it tells you.  Mine tells me

`/dev/mapper/vg00-TmpVol on /tmp type ext4 (rw,`**noexec**`,nosuid,nodev)`

Comment: Another possibility is SELinux permissions. What does the audit.log file say when you try run the script?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a formatted comment.

From the `ls` info page:

> ```
> GNU ‘ls’ uses a ‘.’ character to indicate a file with a security
> context, but no other alternate access method.
> ```

You might try `bash -x ./myscript.sh` to see if something else is causing that error.